# Proving an algebraic identity by a straightforward method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to show the algebraic identity
$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+ ... +xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

I know that this identity can be proved by induction. But I want a straightforward method to deduce this formula. Is there a way to prove this without using induction? I want hints, not answers.

Comment: If you're allowed to use the factorisation of $1-u^n$ – or the sum of the geometric series (it's equivalent), yes.

Comment: A slight problem is that finite sums like the 2nd factor on the right side is defined by induction. That is, the dot dot dot is shorthand for the real definition as a sum which is defined by induction, unless you have some other definition in mind which does **not** use induction.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that
$$
\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k
$$
for $x\neq 1$. But this is clear since
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k+1}=1-x^n.
$$

Comment: I think that I clearly understand your solution. I never thought it was to easy to prove! Thank you for your feedback! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use sigma bashing.

$\begin{array}\\
(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-1-k}
&=x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-1-k}-y\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k+1}y^{n-1-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k}y^{n-1-(k-1)}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k}y^{n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^{k}y^{n-k}+x^n-(y^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^ky^{n-k})\\
&=x^n-y^n\\
\end{array}
$